# HTML form insert with multiple inputs and files

Tags: php, html

I have table where you can add extra row using JS. Each row has input fields.

There are no problems with description and other fields except of type="file"

when i push "submit" only 1 (the first in table's row) image move to destination folder and only 1 image's file name  (also the first in table's row) is written to the DB. Other file names have only date stamp data. example: file name of the 1st image in tables row is 1683578590-45.png, and others have following records 1683578590-

```
$desired_dir = "assets/images/catalog";
                      
$stmt = pdo()->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (order_id, client_id, photo, description, amount, link, user_id, date_add) 
  VALUES (:order_id, :client_id, :photo, :description, :amount, :link, :user_id, :date_add)");

$stmt->bindParam(":order_id",  $lastOrdId);
$stmt->bindParam(":client_id", $lastUsrId);    
$stmt->bindParam(":photo", $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":description", $description);
$stmt->bindParam(":amount", $amount);
$stmt->bindParam(":link", $link);
$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id);
$stmt->bindParam(":date_add", $date);
                    
foreach ($_POST['description'] as $i => $description) {

    $amount = $_POST['amount'][$i];
    $link = $_POST['link'][$i];                      
    $file_name = time() . "-" .$_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i],$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
    
    $stmt->execute();
} 
echo "OK";
```

Html for this inputs:

```
<tr id='addrQual0'>
  <td VALIGN=MIDDLE>1</td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="file" name='img[]'></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="textarea" name='description[]' placeholder='Description' required></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='amount[]' placeholder='Amount' required ></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='link[]' placeholder='Enter link here'></td>
</tr>
<tr id='addrQual1'>
  <td VALIGN=MIDDLE>1</td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="file" name='img[1].img'></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="textarea" name='description[1].description' placeholder='Description' required></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='amount[1].amount' placeholder='Amount' required ></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name='link[1].link' placeholder='Enter link here'></td>
</tr>
```

and etc.

Comment: There's no need to put an explicit index in `name='description[1]'`. Just use `name='description[]'` for all the rows.

Comment: "I have the problem" is not a question. What is the specific problem you're having? Have you tried `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);` to see what they contain?

Comment: There are no problems with description and other fields except of type="file"

when i push "submit" only 1 (the first in table's row) image move to destination folder and only 1 image's file name  (also the first in table's row) is written to the DB. Other file names have only date stamp data. example: file name of the 1st image in tables row is 1683578590-45.png, and others have following record 1683578590-

Comment: Edit the question to add the clarification, don't put it in comments.

Comment: Get rid of `.img` in `name='img[1].img'` It should be `name='img[]'`